# How To Remove Duplication Of Data In DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a VB.NET application that uses a DataGridView control to display data from a database. Currently, it is displaying as follows:

```
54     john         NJ        HRA           1000   
54     john         NJ        DA            2500   
54     john         NJ        BP            12500
```

But I need to display it as follows:

```
54      john  NJ
                     HRA           1000   
                     DA            2500
                     BP            12500
```

Since ID, name and city are repeated, I do not need to display these again. How can I do this?

Comment: try it in cellformatting and static variable compare ..

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

```
DataTable dtDataSource = new DataTable();

dtDataSource.Columns.Add("A");
dtDataSource.Columns.Add("B");
dtDataSource.Columns.Add("C");

dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "1", "1" });
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "1", "2" });
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "1", "3" });
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "1", "1" });
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "1", "2" });
dtDataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "1", "3" });

DataTable dtNew = dtDataSource.Clone();

for (int i = 0; i < dtDataSource.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        if (dtDataSource.Rows[i][0].Equals(dtDataSource.Rows[i - 1][0]))
        {
            dtNew.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", dtDataSource.Rows[i][1], dtDataSource.Rows[i][2] });
        }
        else
        {
            dtNew.Rows.Add(new object[] { dtDataSource.Rows[i][0], "", "" });
            dtNew.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", dtDataSource.Rows[i][1], dtDataSource.Rows[i][2] });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dtNew.Rows.Add(new object[] { dtDataSource.Rows[i][0], "", "" });
        dtNew.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", dtDataSource.Rows[i][1], dtDataSource.Rows[i][2] });
    }
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dtNew;
```

**Your data should be ordered initially.**

I tried to convert VB.Net [here](http://sharetext.org/ZxN1)

Comment: how about for bound data. i have a database with column name and description, but column name some have duplicate name. so how to show just one name with column description has many variable data from the table?

Comment: I think datagridview is not allow a design like that. How do you bind data?

Comment: im using connection string.. if u say so. is there any method to display data like that other than datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is displaying data you could use a UNION of two SQL statements.

The first would retrieve the first three columns plus two columns with empty strings UNION SQL three columns with empty strings and the two columns of data. The field names of the first SQL statement will name the columns.

The data would be read only.

```
    SELECT F1, F2, F3, '' as F4, '' as F5 WHERE ...
    UNION
    SELECT '', '', '', F4, F5 WHERE ...
```

If you are retrieving data for more than one target the SQL will get a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is occurring because of how your database is made.

are you using primary keys and foreign keys?

so that you can easily identify which records only to display